# Using a XIB file for custom Tableview Section Header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, xib

I wanted to use a xib file to customise a tableview section in xcode (objective C), and here ar my files:

SectionHeaderView.xib is a UIView with a UILabel

SectionHeaderView.m

```
#import "SectionHeaderView.h"

@implementation SectionHeaderView

@synthesize sectionHeader;

@end
```

SectionHeaderView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SectionHeaderView : UIView
{
IBOutlet UILabel *sectionHeader;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *sectionHeader;

@end
```

and in my MasterViewController.m

```
#import "SectionHeaderView.h"

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

SectionHeaderView  *header = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

return header;

}
```

It works ok till here, however as soon as I set XIB file owner's custom class to "SectionHeaderView" and connect the Label to  "sectionHeader" I will get the error "NSUnknownKeyException". I wanted to connect these so I could change the label.text by the following code before returning the haeder:

```
header.sectionHeader.text = headerText;
```

I am using storyboard (xcode 4.5) for the MasterViewController.
Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: I have tested it in my app and its working:

```
NSArray *viewArray =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SectionHeaderview" owner:self options:nil];  
UIView *view = [viewArray objectAtIndex:0]; 
UILabel *lblTitle = [view viewWithTag:101]; 
lblTitle.text = @"Text you want to set"; 
return view;
```

Answer (score 15):

You can create a UITableViewCell subclass with an associated xib, and use it as the section header. In this example i will call it **CustomTableViewHeaderCell**.h/.m/.xib and show you how to change the text of a label inside this cell.

- Create an outlet property in your CustomTableViewHeaderCell.h

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sectionHeaderLabel;
- Add a UITableViewCell into the empty CustomTableViewHeaderCell.xib 
  and set the class of the element to **CustomTableViewHeaderCell**
  from the Identity Inspector.
- Set also the Identifier (attribute inspector of the cell) for example
  *CustomIdentifier*.
- Drag a label into the Content View and connect the outlet from the
  **CustomTableViewHeaderCell**  (Not the file owner!).

Then in each ViewController you want to use the table view section header cell:

1) Register your xib to reuse identifier (probably in viewDidLoad):

```
[_yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewHeader" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"];
```

2) Override viewForHeaderInSection to display your custom cell header view

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    CustomTableViewHeaderCell * customHeaderCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"];
    customHeaderCell.sectionHeaderLabel = @"What you want";
    return customHeaderCell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by one of the following way:

1) you have derived SectionHeaderView from `UIView`. derive this class with `UIViewController` instead. This will resolve your issue.

2) Instead of using `IBOutlet` property, Set Tag of `UILabel` in view (say 101).

Discard SectionHeaderview class.

Keep SectionHeaderView.XIB, delete .m and .h files only.

use following code ins Viewforheader method of MasterViewController class:

```
{
    UIViewController *vc=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SectionHeaderview" bundle:nil]

    UILable *lblTitle =[vc.view viewWithTag:101];

    lblTitle.text =@"Text you want to set";

    return vc.view;
}
```

Comment: I tried 2nd way and get an error: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SectionFooterView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: try this: I have tested it in my app and its working:           'code' NSArray *arrviw=  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SectionHeaderview" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *view = [arrviw objectAtIndex:0];                     UILable *lblTitle =[view viewWithTag:101];

lblTitle.text =@"Text you want to set"; return view;

Comment: What are the pros for setting a UIViewController as header for another UIViewController? The header is in fact a UIView. The original question was how to load the nib file as header.