# How to set a custom cell as header or footer of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using Xib files instead of storyboard. I have created a table view with some dummy data. Its working fine, Now I have created a custom cell with some labels and textFields. How can I use it as header or footer of UITableView ?

Comment: you can not use  UITableView cell as header or footer , for that you need to create one view (xib) and you can use it

Comment: cell as header? tableHeaderView is a type of view, not a cell

Comment: How to create a UiView with and Xib ? when i create a new CocoaTouch file and make it subclass of UIView the option of "Also create Xib file" is not check able

Comment: Duplicated with here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556750/using-a-xib-file-for-custom-tableview-section-header

Answer (score 33):

The answer is actually pretty simple.
In `viewForHeaderInSection()` create cell object as you do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` and return it.

Here is sample code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

You can set height for header as:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

Update for Swift 4.2

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

Comment: Adding Tableview cell is not a good solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom view programmatically. I tried the following code. Try it once.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let customview:UIView = UIView();
        let label = UILabel();
        label.text = "ur custom data"
        /*
            You can add any number of subviews you want here
            And don't forget to add it to your customview.
         */
        customview.addSubview(label)
        return customview;
    }
```

similarly you can do the same thing for header also.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Method add the Header of TableView:
In that you can any controls Like UIButton,UIImageView,....etc.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionView = UIView()
        sectionView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,height,width) // For Set the Frame 
        sectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return sectionView
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionView = UIView()
        sectionView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,height,width) // For Set the Frame 
        sectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return sectionView
    }
```

Like Above you can set the Footer of Section and
You can add the size of the header And footer

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0
}
```

Swift 4.0

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let sectionView = UIView()
                sectionView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)// For Set the Frame
                sectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                return sectionView
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let sectionView = UIView()
                sectionView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)// For Set the Frame
                sectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                return sectionView
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
    }
```

Comment: I have created a cstom view which contains an imageView. When i try to use this method with a simple view wotha nackground color it works but not with my custom view